# Joomla 3 don't see article alternative layout

Tags: layout, joomla, joomla3.0, article

I need to use alternative layout for articles from 1 category.
I added layout file to

```
site.root\templates\mytemplate\html\com_content\article\alt_layout.php
```

But I don't see it in article options: there are only "Use Global" and "Default from component".

[image]

No problem with override but **I need additional layout**.

Comment: I found this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378345/alternative-layout-for-article-based-on-category-in-joomla-2-5

But in my view it must be realised in joomla.

Comment: Do not use underscore in your file name. You should rename it to altlayout and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution for this Problem:

delete the underscore ('_') from your layout name like

```
site.root\templates\mytemplate\html\com_content\article\altlayout.php
```

Reload Article and voila :-)!